# Не могу изменить дизайн conteiner Linear layout c TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

У меня есть ArrayList и если я кликаю на какой нибудь item из списка, то он выводится отдельно в screen_activity.xml  и проблема в том, что я почти ничего не могу сделать с дизайном, чаще всего после изменения приложение крашится
как мне сделать хотя бы чтобы вверху показывалось время, батарейка и тд?
ну и сам текст не могу зацентрить и что либо с ним сделать

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
tools:context="com.example.vova.someapp.ScreenActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: в приведенной разметке нет ничего, что могло бы стать причиной описанных проблем, а в описании нет никаких действий, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Укажите в вопросе, какие именно действия приводят к проблемам, как их воспроизвести, если крашится - добавьте так же стектрейс при остановке и связанный с этим код.  В текущем виде вопроса вам поможет только программа "битва экстасенсов"

Comment: хорошо, а как сделать так чтобы у меня вверху показывалось время, связь и т.д.?

Comment: попробуйте еще раз внимательно прочитать первый коммантарий и понять, что паронормальными способностями здесь никто не обладает в такой степени, чтобы угадывать ваши действия. Если все делать "по шаблону", то никаких проблем с показом связи, времени и тд. не будет и именно вы должны показать, что вы делали "не так" чтобы добится таких результатов. Могу предположить, что вам нужно использовать темы, отличные от fullscreen. Сейчас ваш вопрос звучит так: "что делать, чтобы у меня машина заводилась, ехала и тд?" - ответить на это что то полезное может только родственница Ванги по прямой линии

Comment: например когда я меняю LinearLayout на RelativeLayout

Comment: у меня в активити он был обозначен как LinearLayout и потому крашилось приложение
как поменял там на RelativeLayout сразу стало все нормально и кое какие настройки теперь могу внести, например зацентрить все
хотя пока все же не могу верхнюю панельку добавить со временем
может и ее надо в активити добавить?

Comment: стоп, лол, извиняюсь она оказывается есть, но белая и потому я ее не замечал
тогда вопрос как ее сделать темной?